# Return a Value between 1 & 360

Tags: c++, math, rotation, trigonometry, quaternions

I have a function set to return a Value being used in a Quaternin Rotation. Howver when I have a reslt less than 1 or very close to 360 I recieve a result of -nan(ind). Is there a way to return a conclusive result betwen 1 & 360 to avoid any errors in calculaon. Thanks

```
const float ReturnAngle() const
{
    return (acosf(angle) * 180.0f * 2) / PI;
}
```

Update:

These are some results as to wat I receive when checking the value after applying a transformaion rotation to my quatrnion.

```
angle: 359.598
angle: -nan(ind)
angle: 357.843


angle: -nan(ind)
angle: -nan(ind)
angle: 0.798189
angle: 2.16383
angle: 1.75475
angle: -nan(ind)
```

Comment: It's not when you "have a result less than 1 or very close to 360" that you run into problems; it's when `angle`, whatever that is, has certain values. Write the smallest program you can come up with that compiles and runs and shows the problem.

Comment: Note that the input of `acos` cannot be an angle, but a cosine value between -1 and 1

Comment: Your issue likely comes from `angle = 1.000001` with any +/- sign

Comment: add this line to your code `static_assert(angle > 1.0 || angle < -1.0, "Wrong angle input");`

Comment: It might make more sense to clamp your value to -1.0 or 1.0 if you're not looking for this to fail, otherwise you will need to have a regular `assert(angle > 1.0 || angle < -1.0)` from <cassert>. `static_assert` will not work because `angle` is not a compile time value, it seems to be a class member variable.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your post. The point of SO is not only to help you, but to accumulate knowledge. Besides, the [terms of service](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service/public) say that SO has a right to keep your posts forever. You can have your name removed from the post though, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96732/how-do-i-remove-my-name-from-a-post-in-accordance-with-cc-by-sa-4-0

Answer (score 1):

The value that you are passing to `acosf` is outside the allowed range -1 to 1. Review the code that sets the value for `angle` - perhaps you have a bug there. If it is just a rounding error and `angle` is outside the allowed range by a small value, "clamping" it to the valid range may be a good solution.

```
const float ReturnAngle() const
{
    if (angle < -1f) angle = -1f;
    if (angle > +1f) angle = +1f;
    return (acosf(angle) * 180.0f * 2) / PI;
}
```